# What is the name for this kind of matrix (if one exists)?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a scientific name for such a matrix where elements have the same value except at the diagonal? For example:

$$ \begin{bmatrix}x+1 &x&x&...&x\\x&x+2&x&...&x\\x&x&x+3&...&x\\...&...&...&...&...\\x&x&x&...&x+n\end{bmatrix} $$

Note: this matrix appeared in [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1672028/calculate-determinant-a-size-n#1672028).
Thx.

Comment: There's quite a big [list](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_matrices) on Wikipedia, but I see no definition there. I don't think such a matrix is used often enough to have a commonly agreed upon name.

Comment: @ChantryCargill, good list. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If anything, this is a representation of a symmetric matrix, and I believe that
is the closest this we can get to a scientific name for this. I guess one could
consider this a pseudo-diagonal matrix, in the sense that all elements
are the same off the diagonal but the elements off the diagonal
are not necessarily zero.

Comment: No, that's not the accepted meaning of pseudo-diagonal.  A pseudo-diagonal matrix is an $m \times n$ matrix (where $m$ and $n$ can be different) such that $a_{ij} = 0$ if $i \ne j$.